# Why isn't my 'Text' in my css isn't inline with my input i cant figure this out

Tags: css

I am using this codes below to  Add data into my web :

//Codes//

```
.AddData input {

    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.AddData [type='text'] {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px:
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.AddData button {

    transform: translate(120%,-50%);
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ff267e;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}


.AddData tr {
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Below is my html codes i used for my website.

//Html//

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css">
<body>
   <div class ="AddData">
    <form action="add.php" method="POST" name="form1">
        <table width="25%" border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>User ID: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="User_id" required autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="Password" required autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="CPass" required autocomplete="off" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is what it shows on my website i just need the 'User_id' to be inline as the input box.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBPEW.png

Comment: What you have done is correct and even in the image everything is inline. If am wrong, could you please explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: The codes are working properly the problem is that i want the 'Change Password'  as one line and i want the text to be in line as the input.

Comment: can you add your html please ? a fiddle would be great too

Comment: done adding in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use padding instead of margin to add space inside a `td`. I left some commented code for you to check what styles I removed from your code.
There will be some issues you'll have to fix like the difference in font size.

```css
.AddData input {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2.5px;
    /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
}

.AddData [type='text'] {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px; /*; was missing*/
    /* margin-bottom: 6px; */
}

.AddData button {
    transform: translate(120%,-50%);
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ff267e;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}


/* .AddData tr {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
} */

.AddData td {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class ="AddData">
    <form action="add.php" method="POST" name="form1">
      <table width="25%" border="0">
        <tr> 
          <td>User ID: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="User_id" required autocomplete="off"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="Password" required autocomplete="off"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="CPass" required autocomplete="off" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works !! I recently just got into coding so im pretty much a noob haha.

Comment: You're welcome. I would like to add that it will be better to use `div` instead of `table` for layout in the future.

Comment: But any idea on how to change the 'Confirm Password : '?

Comment: If you want it in one line you'll have to make the first column wider.